# StretchDraw to printer.canvas loses the transparency

Tags: delphi, timage

I have a `TImage` with a 24 bit `BMP` (or any other type) and I try to print it to the `Adobe PDF` printer. I set the `transparent` property as `TRUE` but the Bitmap printed in a black background without any transparency.

I tried to set the `canvas.brush` as `bsSolid`, `bsClear` etc but the result is the same.

With `transparent = FALSE` it is printed as expected.

Any suggestions, please ?

Comment: @KJ, but it happens also with the same image converted from the `BMP` to `JPG`. It happens with `AdobePDF`   AND `Microsoft PDF` AND `Microsoft XPS writter`.

Comment: @KJ, BMPs are printed fine with microsoft PDF/XPS. No transparency with JPG/PNG